# How can I extract the strings from a specific node only if it is followed by a specific sibling node in R?

Tags: r

How can I extract the strings in the "source" nodes only if it precedes a "volume" node?

```
xml <- "<doc>
  <head>
    <volume>1</volume>
  </head>
  <ref id='1'>
    <source>a</source>
    <volume>114</volume>
  </ref>
  <ref id='2'>
    <source>b</source>
    <issue>2</issue>
  </ref>
  <ref id='3'>
    <source>c</source>
    <volume>166</volume>
  </ref>
  <ref id='4'>
    <source>d</source>
    <volume>19</volume>
  </ref>
</doc>"
```

I essentially want to get the following output: a, c, d

Comment: Are you using `XML` or `xml2` to parse the xml? The solutions may differ depending on which one you're using.

Comment: so far I've been using XML, but I was looking into xml2

Comment: I can only comment on xml2, but I suspect the process will be similar for something like this. What you're looking for are [xpath axes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp), so something that might work would be along the lines of xml_text(xml, xpath="//volume/preceding-sibling::source")

Comment: I am getting this error " Error in xml_text(xml, xpath = "//volume/preceding-sibling::source") : 
  unused argument (xpath = "//volume/preceding-sibling::source") "

Comment: This worked for me " getNodeSet(xml, path="//volume/preceding-sibling::source") "! Thanks for sharing xpath axes, I'm new to xml.

Answer (score 1):

I edited your example XML to make it more valid (by including a document root and quoting the attribute values).

Then:

```
library(xml2)
library(magrittr) # for pipes %>%
read_xml(xml) %>% 
  xml_find_all(xpath = "//volume/preceding-sibling::source") %>% 
  xml_text()

[1] "a" "c" "d"
```